# Is it possible to use pandas to scrape html tables over multiple web pages?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm looking for ways to scrape all tables on a certain website. The tables are formatted exactly the same in all subpages. The problem is, the urls of those subpages are in this way:
url1 = 'http.../Tom',
url2 = 'http.../Mary',
url3 = 'http.../Jason', such that I cannot set a loop by altering the url incrementally. Are there any possible ways to solve this by pandas?

Comment: Do you know in advance what the urls will be?  Where are you getting the urls?

Comment: How do you use `pandas` in scraping ?

Comment: You can try to use pd.read_html() method, but without having an example of the page it is difficult to suggest anything specific. So could you provide an example?

Comment: An example url is here: http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=S411  Actually I would like to scrape all the race histories of horses from here: http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/SelectHorse.asp

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to use `BeautifulSoup` library first and get all the `table` elements from a webpage and then apply `pd.read_html()`

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the data in each page are actually formatted as HTML `table` elements, and can be processed by pandas. (Of course many page displays that look like tables are not HTML `table` elements; it is as well to check.)

Then the code to process one table might look this this:

```
df = pd.read_html(url, header=0)[0]
```

or this:

```
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

I'm assuming that there is just one table of interest on each of the pages. In fact you might also find that other parameters of `read_html` might need to be varied.

Then the full code would be something like this:

```
stub_url = 'http:// ...'
dfs = []
for ending in ['Tom', 'Mary', 'Jason']:
    one_df = pd.read_html(stub_url + ending, header=0)[0]
    dfs[ending] = one_df
```

Comment: Appreciate that. Unfortunately, I have followed your code but it returns as: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: Sorry, give it a try now.